# wanting pattern for best way to pass function parameters into setTimeout call in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm struggling with the best way to pass all the parameters passed into a function through to the function in `setTimeout`.  That is, in my example below, I pass one parameter, but it seems to me as this gets more complex it gets ugly (multiple parameters).  I'm hoping for a clean pattern to do this since I do it a lot.

```
onSessionTimeComboChange: function (combo, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
    var me = this;
    me.newValue = newValue;
    setTimeout(function () {
        var x = me.newValue;
        debugger;
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just store all those params in an object map? That way you don't have to keep passing in params.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you don't have access to the main function variables in the callback is that the code executed by `setTimeout()` is run in a **separate execution context** to the function from which it was called. In simpler terms, `this` is not the same in the callback.

If you don't want to use Javascript libraries that provide functions to bind a callback to a context (see [*jQuery.proxy*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) and [*underscore.bind*](http://underscorejs.org/#bind)), you would have to write your own non-native `setTimeout` function to fix this.

Here is the solution proposed in the [web api docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout#The_.22this.22_problem) (See section `The "this" problem`):

```
window.setTimeout = function (vCallback, nDelay /*, argumentToPass1, argumentToPass2, etc. */) {
  var oThis = this, aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
  return __nativeST__(vCallback instanceof Function ? function () {
    vCallback.apply(oThis, aArgs);
  } : vCallback, nDelay);
};
```

If you don't want to go that far, an improvement to your code would be to pass the arguments to the callback as parameters of `setTimeout`:

```
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(func, delay, [param1, param2, ...]);
```

Check the [JavaScript web api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) for more details.

So in your example, you could just write something like:

```
setTimeout(function (x) {
    debugger;
}, 100, newValue);
```

Answer (score 4):

Javascript supports **closures** so you can indeed pass any parameters you need to any callback without much effort:

```
function bar(x, y, z) {
    console.log([x, y, z]);
}

for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    (function(x, y, z){
        setTimeout(function(){bar(x, y, z);}, i*1000+1000);
     })(i, i*2, i*3);
}
```

The only tricky part is that you cannot just say

```
setTimeout(function(){bar(i, i*2, i*3)}, i*1000+1000);
```

because the closure captures the **variables** (not the current values), so all the registered functions would actually use the same `i` value in this case.